# How can I make the text from an image transparent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, images, background

How do I make the white text in the middle transparent. I can easily make a transparent layer and remove the white background from the overall image, but how to I do the text, its too small to individual click and remove each letter.I've got Photoshop and G.I.M.P[image]

Comment: cant you get hold of a vector version of this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a version of the image that is black and white and then invert it to that you have a white logo on a black background. You may have to use levels or brightness and contrast to get solid black and pure white.

Then use this black and white image as a LAYER MASK and fill the layer in question with a solid block of the logo colour. Like this:

[image]

Done.